# Why say "Wait your turn" but "Wait FOR..." everything else?

Tags: idioms, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Why in English is the word "for" not used in the phrase "wait your turn?"  Wouldn't it make more sense to say "Wait for your turn" as for other things on which one waits?

- Wait for the stop light *not* Wait the stop light.
- Wait for (until) Tuesday *not* Wait Tuesday.
- Wait for you to arrive *not* Wait you to arrive.

Comment: We also say Wait a minute/ second, and often leave out 'for' in sentences referring to time: 'We waited another three days before we heard back"

Answer (score 7):

> Wait for your turn

This is equally acceptable, however less used. Wait your turn is a proper and shortened way of stating the same thing, albeit in a slightly different manner.

> Wait your turn

However this is much more common in modern day English.

Both are proper and acceptable however.